# How to add Rabbit Hole to a custom content entity

Tags: entities, 9

We use the module [Rabbit Hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) for nodes and terms. Now we would like to use it also for our custom [content entities](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/content-entity). I have tried to find some information, how to add the Rabbit Hole to a custom content entity. I have found some related information, but maybe there is some manual, which would be more specific.

I have found:

- [Support for entity types created with ECK](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole/issues/2299561)
- [Storage entity with Rabbit Hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/storage/issues/3220934)

Comment: You need to write a plugin of type `RabbitHoleEntityPlugin` (extending from [`RabbitHoleEntityPluginBase`](https://api.druphelp.com/api/rabbit_hole/src%21Plugin%21RabbitHoleEntityPluginBase.php/class/RabbitHoleEntityPluginBase/8)). There doesn't seem to be any documentation so going through the base class and instances in the submodules (rh_node, rh_taxonomy, rh_user, etc) seems like the best place to start

Comment: Actually the best docs are probably the method comments in `RabbitHoleEntityPluginInterface`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for v 1.x.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\RabbitHoleEntityPlugin;

use Drupal\my_module\Plugin\RabbitHoleEntityPluginBase;

/**
 * Implements rabbit hole behavior for custom eck entity type.
 *
 * @RabbitHoleEntityPlugin(
 *   id = "rh_my_eck_type",
 *   label = @Translation("Custom ECK entity"),
 *   entityType = "custom_eck_entity_type_id"
 * )
 */
class CustomEckEntityType extends RabbitHoleEntityPluginBase {}
```

Optionally if you want allow override rh rules per each entity then implement this hook:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_base_field_info().
 */
function my_module_entity_base_field_info(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() === 'custom_eck_entity_type_id') {
    $fields = \Drupal::service('rabbit_hole.entity_extender')
      ->getRabbitHoleFields('custom_eck_entity_type_id');
    return $fields;
  }
}
```

*Note: RH v.2.x architecture is different and other content entities should be supported of of the box. v.1 and v.2 are incompatible*